# Possible to compile/encode JavaScript to binary to hide code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My NodeJS app of course contains all business logic and algorithms, and if I install this on a customers server, then they can read my source code, which I want to keep as secret as possible to protect my business.

PHP have several tools which can take the php project and encode it into bytecode, which is exactly what I would like to be able to do for JS/NodeJS.

There are several NodeJS packers, which just bundles it all into an executable, but the plain JS source code is still in there.

**Question**

How to protect your JS/NodeJS source/product when it is installed on a customers server?

Comment: Is uglyfying an answer ? (becaus eit make the code unreadable by human eyes but its still not binary)

Comment: It would be better than nothing, but I'd really would like bytecode if possible.

Comment: There's web assembly (wasm), but that can be "de-compiled" back to a readable form (as can obfuscated code). Really, if you're sending software out over the internet to any client that requests it, you cannot expect any real security. The only real way to protect intellectual property is to keep it on your own secure servers.

Comment: No, there is no bytecode for JavaScript. Maybe WebAssembly will change that, but I don't think node will support that.

Comment: There is no intermediary compile target like PHP bytecode for NodeJS that you could use.

Comment: [Nobody cares about your code](https://mortoray.com/2015/04/20/nobody-cares-about-your-code/)

Comment: as a sidenote, bytecode does not make anything unreadable. Filebot, a paid java application, has a licensing logic that can be easily bypassed. Minecraft is compiled into bytecode and even obfuscated, yet it does not prevent thousands of mods popping up on the internet. Even companies who invested millions in DRMs can't prevent reverse engineering of their software and stop crack releases. As long as the user owns the hardware, you can't do anything about that.

Comment: To my knowledge, `pkg` compiles an app to bytecode in case the project has `private` flag.

Comment: Compiling doesn't hide the secrets. It only makes it harder to spot them. Same goes for example for iOS apps. The binaries are encrypted, but after decoding for executable you can view them with a JailBroken iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PHP have several tools which can take the php project and encode it into bytecode

There are decompilers as well.

For this specific case a minifier and [`pkg`](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) will do the job. This provides a workable application that cannot be *easily* modified in case a customer intends to breach a contract or license. A minifier alone won't be enough because in production source maps are necessary for correct debugging, while minified JS can be fully reverted to original JS in presence of source map.

There's [`bytenode`](https://github.com/OsamaAbbas/bytenode) that uses V8 functionality to compile scripts to byte code and evaluate it. It won't make things faster like would be expected from a compiler, quite the contrary.

Comment: Why does `bytenode` make the code slower? Shouldn't it also be faster because v8 won't have to compile js to bytecode?

Comment: @LuketheGeek Cache allows for some improvement on launch but a script runs slower. This is supported by several benchmarks and statements from devs I've seen, also implied by the fact that Node doesn't do that itself. bytenode introduces small overhead itself and likely disables some optimizations that are normally done in V8. Could be different if V8 were fine-tuned for AOT compilation but it's JIT. I'd be interested myself in detailed explanation why exactly V8 bytecode performs slower in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library to turn plain text javascript files for nodeJS into binaries. It is called bytenode

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytenode

Bytenode allows you to compile a Javascript file into .JSC
then you can call it from your javascript code using require

once you loaded the bytenode module into your nodejs code, you can call your binary file(s) using "require".